# Template file structure , wordpress hook for altering the template

Tags: plugin-development, functions, jquery, templates, hooks

i need to convert a html structure to theme. So this is my html structure

```
<html>
   <head>
    .................
  </head>
<body>
   <div class="main">
      <div class="inner">
            ....
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    ...
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

so for this in **header.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
  .................
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
 <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

in **footer.php**

```
<div class="footer">
  ...
 </div>
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

So now my need is to

```
<div class="main">
          <div class="inner">
                ....
          </div>
      </div>
```

i need to write this main and inner div in a separate file and call this file in each template .is there **any hook** available ???

that is i need to append

```
 <div class="main">
              <div class="inner">
```

after body (or after **get_header()** )and i need to append

```
</div>
</div>
```

before `<div class="footer">` or(before **get_footer()**) 
 Please help .I don't want to re write header.php, footer.php for including this div.it is a seprate file or it is append via using any of the worpress hook .

Comment: To be honest, you are really better of adding those HTML structures in the correct files where it should be, so the bad news is, you need to alter `header.php` and `footer.php`. There is no **exact** hooks to properly add those divs where you exactly need them

Comment: thanks Pieter Gossen. I know this solution .But my client didn't allow me to do this, that's why i am searching the solution. Is any jqery methods are avilable?

Comment: Possibly template parts could help?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part.  This would allow you to segment the main body.